# Jquery: getting return value of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, return-value

I would like to create a basic generic function with jquery to put all elements of an html list into an Array. Everything seem to be ok but I meet some problems to get the return value. I know this is a basic problem so I hope you could help me to solve it.

```
  <script>
        function listeToArrayById(idListe){ 
            $(function(){
                var listChildren = $("#" + idListe).children(); //puts all li children in var listChildren
                var arrayListChildren = [];
                $.each(listChildren, function(key, value){
                    arrayListChildren.push($(this).text());
                })
                return arrayListChildren; // here it's ok arrayListChildren = ["a", "b", "c"] 
            })
        }
        var ulChildren = listeToArrayById("list1");
        window.console.log(ulChildren); // here is my problem because ulChildren is undefined ... I should get an array ["a", "b", "c"]
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="list1">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
    </ul>
    </body>
```

Comment: Why the `$(function(){` inside your function? When you call your function it doesn't execute it since you put the  `$(function(){`  in your function so it waits for the DOM to load. Put the `var ulChildren = listeToArrayById("list1");
        window.console.log(ulChildren);` inside the DOM ready and remove from your function and it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using *`document ready handler`* in a wrong way,

```
function listeToArrayById(idListe){ 
     var listChildren = $("#" + idListe).children();
     var arrayListChildren = [];
     $.each(listChildren, function(key, value){
        arrayListChildren.push($(this).text());
     })
     return arrayListChildren; // here it's ok arrayListChildren = ["a", "b", "c"] 
}

$(function(){
  var ulChildren = listeToArrayById("list1");
  console.log(ulChildren); 
});
```

And you could simplify your code like below,

```
function listeToArrayById(idListe){ 
     return $("#" + idListe).children().map(function(){
           return this.textContent
     }).get();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir it works !. I am reputation of "11" on stackoverflow ... I need a "15" reputation to be able to vote for good answers .... that means I need only 1 person vote on my answer and I'll be 15 reputation.

Comment: @zm455 You can still accept the answers. If you feel that this answer has helped you, then try to press the tick mark present inside my answer. And this is not a compulsion. :)

Comment: someone has voted for my question so now I can vote for your answer. Thank you very much sir have a good day ;-)